# opening browser using a get method url

Tags: c#, url, browser, get

I'm trying to open the default web browser from my application, so far I'm using:

```
Process.Start("view.html");
```

And it works, but what if I want to open the browser with an url like: "view.html?var=something"

using the Process.Start trows a file not found error and I cant find a way to tell it to open still the file but with the get method specified.

thanks for the help

EDIT:

Done it in this way:

```
String browserStr = Path.GetFullPath(Config.PAGE_LOCAL_URL) + _p;
Process.Start("opera.exe", browserStr).WaitForInputIdle();
```

Anyway, there is a way to find the default browser and pass it to the function so that I should not specify it?

Comment: have you tried `@"view.html?var=something"` ?

Comment: yes, not working. What the @ does anyway?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx  I thought that perhaps your ? character etc were getting ignored

Comment: what browser did you open on? I tried a similar with a youtube video link (includes the ? wildcard) and it worked fine in firefox

try `Process.Start("firefox.exe", "view.html?var=something");` (or different browser anyway)

Comment: I tried this now with opera.exe, problem is that the browser now opens to "http://view.html/?xml=19052013.xml". I want to open it to the local view.html page

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Process.Start("view.html", "?var=something");
```

Comment: Im thinking the variables should b in the arguments section

Comment: I don't get exceptions with this code, anyway it still opens the page view.html without the get method params